# What place does Smirti works have in Hinduism?

Tags: contradiction, truth

Some Smirti works are in contradiction with Shruti canon, so I want to ask how the derivative canon is considered? What type of people read it? [(eg)](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16920/any-examples-where-a-smriti-has-contradicted-a-sruti-statement?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *"What type of people read it?"* - would you be kind enough to explain what do you mean by this?!

Comment: See if the above post solves your query or not @Buraian

Comment: @RickRoss I'm asking if it is considered in the main story line. For a person who only wants to study what Hinduism is, sometimes these derivative works have contradicting statements to shruti works.

Comment: So, I'm trying to figure out what place smirti works have.. are they alternative Hinduism?

Comment: The traditional/scriptural position is this -- Sruti (Veda) has the highest authority, Smriti is next. Puranas etc have less authority than Smritis. Smritis are essentially part of Vedas as they crop from Kalpasutras (which is one of the six Vedangas). @Buraian