# How did King Kakudmi reach Brahma Loka with his daughter Revathi?

Tags: brahma, lokas

I read that King Kakudmi with his daughter Revati reached Brahma Loka experiencing time-dilation. Can anyone tell me how **they** managed to travel?

Comment: It happens through  tapasya and yoga.

Comment: I've quoted some related  verses from Upanishads [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16421/277).

Comment: one way - kanya-daan of your valid kanya to a valid brahmachari gets you brahmaloka according to mantra 'kanya kanaka sampanna.. brahma loka jigeeshaya'

Comment: @What do you mean by valid brahmachari? I don't have deep knowledge regarding saints but I believe brahmachari is the one who never gets married. If this is true then how one can do kanya-daan to him?

Comment: is it just a philosophical concept?

Comment: Very interesting question! maybe he was sent there like Vishwwamitra sent Trishanku?

Comment: I feel we have the wrong perspective here. Clearly these are myths intended to convey something more profound, such as time dilation. That they were able to conceive of such relativity of spacetime thousand years before Einstein should be the focus of our appreciation. The characters, Brahmaloka, etc are only symbols that are used to frame the central idea. I honestly don't see any value in taking the details of the story literally, and trying to find serious answers.

Answer (score 3):

**King Kakudmi reached Brahma Loka with his daughter Revathi with the help of his *yogic powers***

It can be inferred from the following words of Narada:

> **prapto yoga-balenapi brahmalokam** shubhavaham kanya-varam pariprashöum
> brahmanam prananama ha
>
> **By his mystic power he traveled to Brahmaloka**. His intention to ask
> for a proper husband for his daughter, he bowed before the god
> Brahma
>
> [[7, 6.3:  Lord Balarama's Wedding, Garga Samhita]](http://wikikrishna.com/index.php?title=GS_6.3:_Lord_Balarama%27s_Wedding)

Comment: I find that vague. What are mystic yogic powers? Have other people used yogic powers?

Comment: Yes, Yogic power, as told in Sanskrit. You can also read about Krishna-Arjuna meeting Lord Siva from the Mahabharata. @Wikash_

Comment: What is there to find?

Comment: @Wikash_ similar scenario of going together along with Yoga.

Comment: Can you add that to your answer?

Comment: @Wikash_ what is the need of that? I told you to understand the phenomenon. If you are interested, i can provide the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109661/discussion-between-hanugm-and-wikash).