# Is 'yoga' the sole means to experience colossal time dilation?

Tags: scripture, yoga, time, lokas

Within the vast knowledge presented in Hindu scriptures, there are instances of individuals transitioning into the future. These transitions often occur when these individuals traverse to different 'lokas' and then return to their original place. Although this phenomenon might be interpreted as time dilation, it essentially represents a form of travel into the future.

A recurring observation across these incidents is the usage of 'Yoga' as a technique to accomplish such extraordinary journeys. Notable examples include:

#1: [King Kakudmi's Travel to Brahmaloka](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/40823/661)

> prapto **yoga-balenapi** brahmalokam shubhavaham kanya-varam pariprashöum
> brahmanam prananama ha
>
> By his mystic power he traveled to Brahmaloka. His intention to ask
> for a proper husband for his daughter, he bowed before the god Brahma
>
> [[7, 6.3: Lord Balarama's Wedding, Garga Samhita]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/garga-samhita-english/d/doc1126247.html)

#2: [The Journey of Mahasena with the Sage's Son](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/53402/661)

> The saint smiled at this and said: 'You do not seem to know yoga.
> Well, close your eyes.'  The king closed his eyes; the saint forthwith
> entered into him, took the other's subtle body and left the gross body
> in the hole. Then by his yogic power the saint entered the hill with
> this subtle body snatched from the other which was filled with the
> desire of seeing the empire within the bowels of the hill. Once inside
> he roused up the sleeping individual to dream. The latter now found
> himself held by the saint in the wide expanse of ether.
>
> He was alarmed on looking in all directions and requested the saint,
> 'Do not forsake me lest I should perish in this illimitable space.'
>
> The saint laughed at his terror and said, 'I shall never forsake you.
> Be assured of it. Now look round at everything and have no fear.'
>
> The king took courage and looked all round. He saw the sky above,
> enveloped in the darkness of night and shining with stars. He ascended
> there and looked down below; he came to the region of the moon and was
> benumbed with cold. Protected by the saint, he went up to the Sun and
> was scorched by its rays. Again tended by the saint, he was refreshed
> and saw the whole region a counterpart of the Heaven. He went up to
> the summits of the Himalayas with the saint and was shown the whole
> region and also the earth. Again endowed with powerful eye-sight, he
> was able to see far-off lands and discovered other worlds besides this
> one. In the distant worlds there was darkness prevailing in some
> places; the earth was gold in some; there were oceans and island
> continents traversed by rivers and mountains; there were the heavens
> peopled by Indra and the Gods, the asuras, human beings, the rakshasas
> and other races of celestials. He also found that the saint had
> divided himself as Brahman in Satyaloka, as Vishnu in Vaikunta, and as
> Siva in Kailasa while all the time he remained as his original-self
> the king ruling in the present world. **The king was struck with wonder
> on seeing the yogic power of the saint**.
>
> The sage's son said to him: '**This sightseeing has lasted only a single
> day according to the standards prevailing here, whereas twelve
> thousand years have passed by in the world you are used to. So let us
> return to my father**'. Saying so, he helped the other to come out of
> the hill to this outer world.
>
> [[76-96, Chapter 12, Gnana Kanda, Tripura Rahasya]](https://www.aghori.it/chapter_8-14.htm)

#3: Lila's Experiences with Ma Saraswathi

> Lila with ma Saraswathi experienced it many times. The story is from
> [section 15](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118069.html) to [section 60](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118118.html). Lila achieved this ultimatly with
> the help of yoga only.

The evident link between **Yoga and travelling into far future** in these accounts prompts an exploration into the exclusivity of this relationship. Specifically, is 'Yoga' the only pathway to achieve such travel into the future as documented in the scriptures? Are there instances in these texts where such travel has been achieved without the explicit usage of Yoga? I invite any insights into alternate methods of time travel, especially those involving journeys through different 'lokas'.

Comment: I saw a vote for closing. There is no way this question falls into the category of 'Scientific speculation'. The question is simple: Are there any instances in scriptures where individuals traveled in time or experienced time dilation without the help of yoga?

Comment: time travel is not a logical concept. time dilation is.

Comment: Yeah @mar but time dilation can be used to travel in time to the future... In the three examples, they did the same using Yoga...

Comment: no - u cannot 'travel' to the past or future. u can know about them. that's all. you cannot influence. time dilation just means that time feels slower or faster in different planets. e.g. in a rotating fan, the point near center of fan travels at slower speed that a point near edge of blade. but total time to make 1 revolution is same. so whatever we experience in 1 day, higher beings experience within 1 second.

Comment: @mar Do you mean king Kakumdi did not go to Dwapara yuga?